# Python:pedestrian detection opencv code did not run?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a project that need to count number of people in a picture and i'm try to use the pedestrian detection code in the following link:

http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/

```
    import the necessary packages
    from __future__ import print_function
    from imutils.object_detection import non_max_suppression
    from imutils import paths
    import numpy as np 
    import argparse
    import imutils
    import cv2

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--images", required=True, help="path to images directory")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector()).

    # loop over the image paths
    for imagePath in paths.list_images(args["images"]):
    print("Hello world")
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
    image = imutils.resize(image, width=min(400, image.shape[1]))
    orig = image.copy()

    # detect people in the image
    (rects, weights) = hog.detectMultiScale(image, winStride=(4, 4),
    padding=(8, 8), scale=1.05)

# draw the original bounding boxes
for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
    cv2.rectangle(orig, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

# apply non-maxima suppression to the bounding boxes using a
# fairly large overlap threshold to try to maintain overlapping
# boxes that are still people
rects = np.array([[x, y, x + w, y + h] for (x, y, w, h) in rects])
pick = non_max_suppression(rects, probs=None, overlapThresh=0.65)

# draw the final bounding boxes
for (xA, yA, xB, yB) in pick:
    cv2.rectangle(image, (xA, yA), (xB, yB), (0, 255, 0), 2)

# show some information on the number of bounding boxes
filename = imagePath[imagePath.rfind("/") + 1:]
print("[INFO] {}: {} original boxes, {} after suppression".format(
    filename, len(rects), len(pick)))

# show the output images
cv2.imshow("Before NMS", orig)
cv2.imshow("After NMS", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

In the line 20: `for imagePath in paths.list_images(args["images"]):` my program pass this line and jump into the end. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you gave the program a directory for images? It looks like the paths in paths.list_images(args["images"]) is an empty list so the for loop has nothing to run on

Comment: @AmitayNachmani Oh right, thank you, I forgot to make a folder of the images.